# Select one div using a CSS Class from another non-parent div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there a way to select `<div class="widget-area">` only if there exists a `<div class="store-content">` before it?

HTML Structure:

```
<!--Store Content Div-->
<div id="content" role="main" class="store-content twentythirteen">...</div>

<div id="tertiary" class="sidebar-container" role="complementary">
    <div class="sidebar-inner">
        <!--Widget Area Div-->
        <div class="widget-area">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was thinking something like

```
.store-content~.widget-area {

}
```

Would Select `.widget-area` but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were close, use:

```
.store-content ~ div .widget-area {
    color:red;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5s8Lw/)

`~` is the general sibling selector but `.store-content` and `.widget-area` aren't siblings. You need the sibling of `.store-content` and then you can select a .widget-area child.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. Is that because element1~element2 must be on the same hierarchical level?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. They just need to be siblings in general. It differs from the direct sibling selector, `+` where they must be siblings and adjacent.